# question about background check - discrepancy

Tags: background-check, employment-gaps

I hope this message finds you well.

I was offered a job about three weeks ago. During my background check, I stated that I had worked for my previous employer for five years. However, I did not get to mention that I first worked for the company as a contractor for a year before becoming a permanent employee. The background report is showing a discrepancy, so I sent the background company a copy of my W-2 while I was a contractor. However, I did work technically for the company for five years. Will this raise a red flag for my employer, who offered me the position?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this raise a red flag for my employer, who offered me the
> position?

It will raise a flag because the dates you provided won't match the information from your previous employer. Because many companies outsource the employee verification process your previous employer will give the date in their records.  The year before that you worked for a different company that had a contract with a company you later joined. The W-2 from that contracting company doesn't mention any customers they had.

While it will raise a flag we have no idea what color that flag will be. So be prepared to to give them all the information regarding your employer, the dates of employment, and how to verify that employment. This could slow down the background check process, because they will need to go back and get more information.

> However, I did work technically for the company for five years.

Don't use the words "technically I worked for..." you worked for a contracting company. That isn't a problem, just make sure you document your dates of employment accurately.